# Get cassandra keyspace with double quotes

Tags: bash, cassandra-3.0

How to get Cassandra keyspace schema which has double quotes. I am getting an error by adding double quotes.

```
cqlsh -e "desc keyspace "OpsCenter"";
```

Comment: `cqlsh -e 'desc keyspace "OpsCenter"'` might do what you want.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a problem in the code (incorrect use of quotes).  The report includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @pjh it didn't work.
cqlsh -e 'desc keyspace "OpsCenter"'

<stdin>:1:Keyspace 'opscenter' not found.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
cqlsh -e "desc keyspace \"OpsCenter\"";
```

Comment: It did not work.
cqlsh -e "desc keyspace \"OpsCenter\"";

<stdin>:1:Keyspace 'opscenter' not found.

Comment: Could you also send the output of this command? `DESCRIBE keyspaces;`
This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbQqj.png) is result of this solution.